# Split an array of dictionaries into n array of dictionaries in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, nsdictionary

I have an array containing n dictionaries and would like to split it in n arrays of x elements contained in an array.

input : array of n element
output : array of n arrays of x elements

For the moment I did this:

```
    NSMutableArray *contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int counter = 0;
    for (id contact in pfContacts)
    {
        counter++;
        [test addObject:contact];
        if (counter%80 == 0 || counter == [pfContacts count])
        {
            int index = counter/81;
            [contacts insertObject:test atIndex:index];
            [test removeAllObjects];
        }
    }
```

but i'm getting an array of empty arrays

Comment: and what exactly your problem is?

Comment: Show what you tried and explain what it does wrong.

Comment: Can you describe what the problem you're getting ?

Comment: see my code in the edit

Comment: It's really unclear to use arrays of dictionaries instead of custom class objects. Try to refactor your code, it may simplify your problem

Answer (score 0):

You are getting problem in this

```
if (counter%80 == 0 || counter == [pfContacts count])
        {
            int index = counter/81;
            [contacts insertObject:test atIndex:index];
            [test removeAllObjects];
        }
```

Because if counter is equal to 80 than if condition will work but in this condition you are using this

```
int index = counter/81;
```

Its means

```
 int index = counter/81;  && 80/81 =  0.98
```

so It's getting error.. 
Change it as

```
int index = counter/80;
```

and try again ... May be helpfull...